# How to run SQL Script using specific parameters PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I need to run a SQL file (to create a user) from within my PHP. I know how this is done:

```
$commands = file_get_contents("sql/create_usr.sql")
$commands = explode(";", $commands);
foreach($commands as $command){
    if($command){
        $success += (@mysql_query($command)==false ? 0 : 1);
        $total += 1;
    }
}
```

How do I run the SQL file with specific parameters (e.g. username, password) from a PHP file. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what you need `if(trim($command))`? The entire ext/mysql PHP extension, which provides all functions named with the prefix mysql_, is officially deprecated as of PHP v5.5.0 and will be removed in the future.

Comment: How then, do I issue sql commands - is mysqli the only way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use a simple shell execution for this, instead of splitting the file with PHP:

```
shell_exec( 'mysql DATABASE -u USERNAME -pPASSWORD < sql/create_usr.sql' );
```

To test, if you can run a SQL-Query using `shell_exec` you might want to try this code:

```
echo shell_exec( 'mysql DATABASE -u USERAME -pPASSWORD -e "SELECT DATABASE();" 2>&1' );
```

Comment: while shell_exec does work, it does not appear to run sql files. For testing I am using the following simple code:- create table       `example(
    me varchar(22)
);`

Comment: For me it's working as expected. But in your case, you might have to use the full path to the mysql binary. So on a Unix system, somethin like `/usr/bin/mysql` should work.

Comment: See my lastest update for some code to check the SQL execution.

Comment: Amazingly, it didn't. With an example user called myuser and password of mypasswd, the full line 
    shell_exec( 'C:\xampp2\mysql\bin\mysql.exe clothe -u myuser     -pmypasswd < C:\xamp2\htdocs\sql\create_usr.sql' ); 
failed to work!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: No error - nothing happened. No table created even with code above.

Comment: What do you get when you run this code: `mysql clothe -u myuser -pmypasswd -e "SELECT DATABASE();" 2>&1`

Comment: by echoing the shell_exec I get this: 'mysql' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
From the command line (if it helps), this:-
`   ` ------------+
      DATABASE() |
     ------------+
      clothe     |
     ------------+`

Comment: Oh sorry, in your case you have have to use the full path. Try: `C:\xampp2\mysql\bin\mysql clothe -u myuser -pmypasswd -e "SELECT DATABASE();" 2>&1`

Comment: Or simply add `C:\xampp2\mysql\bin` to your PATH environment variable.

Comment: I get similar output - DATABASE clothe

Comment: So that at least it's possible to execute a command against the SQL database using `shell_exec`. Than the issue has to be in your file with the SQL queries. If I run a broken query (like `create table example( me varcha(22) );`) I get a ERROR 1064. What do you get (don't forget the "2>&1" at the end)?

Comment: `echo(shell_exec( 'C:\xampp2\mysql\bin\mysql clothe -u myuser -pmypasswd < create_usr.sql 2>&1' ));` outputs nothing when create_usr.sql contains a similar (the same) error.

Comment: Are you sure the the `create_usr.sql` is in the same folder than the PHP script that calls the command. Because if not, you are passing a non-existing file to mysql and you get no response, even no error.

Comment: Yes - that was the problem. With that (silly) error fixed, the end result is the same error - 1064

Comment: So you can now execute a SQL statement from a file?

Answer (score 1):

Read your file line by line and the execute the sentense

```
$handle = fopen("inputfile.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        // process the line read.
    }
} else {
    // error opening the file.
} 
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: There might not be an SQL query on each line and some queries might be split up to several lines.

Comment: I'm afraid that is the case